# Visual Studio 2012 several actions at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating an app using VB2012 that uses the Atbash Cipher (If ur unfamiliar, it is a cipher where you replace "a" with "z", "b" with "y", etc...)
So lets say the code says:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text

        Label1.Text = Label1.Text.Replace("a", "z")
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text.Replace("z", "a")
    End Sub
```

and the textbox read "az". So, by pressing the button, the "a" is replaced by "z", so the message becomes "zz". Then, the second line of code applies, so the "z" is replaced by "a", the message becoming "aa" instead of "za". The question is, how do I run BOTH lines of codes at the same time, so the "a" would become "z" at the same time the "z" becomes an "a". Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to do it 'at the same time', you just need to find the algorithm that correctly executes the Atbash Cipher on your string. So first think about the algorithm; then start coding it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See here for a full explanation:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: You need to mark some of the answers as accepted. You fill find that you will get more answers and better answers if you at least let people know your questions are answered.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lookup table and transform the text. When you create a new table object, it will generate the lookup table internally. You can call the instance method Transform on any string argument. This will return the cipher text.

```
Public Class AtbashTable
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Lookup table to shift characters.
    ''' </summary>
    Private _shift As Char() = New Char(Char.MaxValue - 1) {}

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Generates the lookup table.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub New()
        ' Set these as the same.
        For i As Integer = 0 To Char.MaxValue - 1
            _shift(i) = CChar(i)
        Next
        ' Reverse order of capital letters.
        For c As Char = "A"C To "Z"C
            _shift(CInt(c)) = CChar("Z"C + "A"C - c)
        Next
        ' Reverse order of lowercase letters.
        For c As Char = "a"C To "z"C
            _shift(CInt(c)) = CChar("z"C + "a"C - c)
        Next
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Apply the Atbash cipher.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Function Transform(value As String) As String
        Try
            ' Convert to char array
            Dim a As Char() = value.ToCharArray()
            ' Shift each letter.
            For i As Integer = 0 To a.Length - 1
                Dim t As Integer = CInt(a(i))
                a(i) = _shift(t)
            Next
            ' Return new string.
            Return New String(a)
        Catch
            ' Just return original value on failure.
            Return value
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Usage in your `Button click` event:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  AtbashTable x = new AtbashTable();
  Label1.Text = x.Transform(TextBox1.Text);
End Sub
```